# How to extract a second tier property of json object from server response

Tags: angular

I'm new in angular and I'm stack in simple task.
Using http.get() method I get from the server this json object like this:

```
{
   Data : {Search:[{}, {}, ...], ...}
   ...
}
```

After doing code like this:

```
var dataObject = this.httpRequest.Get()
        .map(item=> item["Data"]);
```

I'm success extract the Data property of this object, but my goal is to extract the Search property of Data property. But after doing this code

```
var dataObject = this.httpRequest.Get()
    .map(item=> item["Data"]).map(temp=>temp["Search"]);
```

I'm extract an undefined object. I guess that it is simple task and I miss some simple solution. My question is how to extract the Serch property of Data property of JSON object from the server?

Comment: Do you get Search object when you `console.log(item["Data"])`?

Comment: after this code                                                                                                    var dataObject = this.httpRequest.Get()
    .map(item=> item["Data"])
    .subscribe(val => console.log(val));
In my console I will get:    {"Search":[{"Title":"The Godfather","Year":"1972","imdbID":"tt0068646", ...}, ...]

Comment: Ok, here `val.Search` should give you what you need.

Comment: It is magic, but I'm still get the undefined object, I can't understand it. This approach should work. Maybe this is beacause Search is an array of objects?

Comment: try this instead `this.httpRequest.Get().map(item=> item.Data.Search)`

Comment: I solve it! I will answer to my question below.

Answer (score 0):

Just try like this `item["Data"].Search` or `item["Data"]["Search"]` . So here basically you're targeting Search property of Data object

Comment: Unfortunately, neither of the two methods worked. I'm still get an undefined value;(

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that Data property is string, not a JSON object, that is why I can't extract the Search array. The solution is

```
var dataObject = this.httpRequest.Get()
    .map(item=>  JSON.parse(item.Data))
    .subscribe(val =>{ 

      console.log(val.Search);
    }
      );
```

Comment: Which version of angular you using? If version 4.3+ you must use `HttpClient` which would auto parse JSON for you and you don't need to parse it manually.